# Installing and using DCPCrypt2 in Delphi 10.4

Tags: delphi

I was using Lazarus with DCPCrypt2 and now I moved over to Delphi 10.4 Sydney and I am trying to install the DCPCrypt2 for Delphi (up to XE7 or 2009, whichever was later) and having no luck, except for pulling what little hair I have left - that I can do no problem.

Could someone please explain to me how to install DCPCrypt2 into Delphi 10.4, how to get the controls into the palette like I was easily able to do in Lazarus and how to set up the paths so that Delphi always knows where to look to find DCPCrypt.

All my code was written in Lazarus using DCPCrypt2 and after looking at Lockbox3, I would rather stick with DCPCrypt2 if I could.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526531/dcpcrypt-installation-use-delphi-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open one of packages (DCP_XE6.dpk) and save is as something like DCP_XEX4.dpk
2. Rightclick in project manager | install package - component available at designtime
3. Go to Tools|Options, navigate to Language|Delphi|Library and add this component path to "Library path" - compiler needs this to build your projects

That's it.

Comment: Thank you Robert.  I am having a hard time following step 2. Which window is the project manager? What do I right click on? Everything I right click on does not have the install package option.  I feel rather stupid because I am smarter than this. Any further help is appreciated.

Comment: So I created a bpl file out of DCrypt2 and installed it - all seemed to go fine, but there is no tab for DCPCrypt ciphers or encryption. How do I see if it even created those?

Comment: Under Packages, DCPCrypt is there. It is checked. I cannot see a tab with the design time modules. If I click on the package in the package manager and click the button 'components', no components show. Some other packages are like that and others have graphical buttons in them. In Lazarus, there are graphics buttons for the tabs. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: view|Tool windows|Palette will show the component palette. In the search box type "DCP" and you should see all DCP components

Comment: So I was able to install it successfully (Finally!) but when I add my code, in the uses clause, the following throws errors: DCPcrypt2, DCPsha256, DCPrijndael, md5, base64 - and I did add the DCPCrypt2 main directory, Hashes and Ciphers to the environment path in Delphi options for Win64. I also get an error that says 'F2048: Bad Unit Format DCPCrypt2.dcu - expected 34.0 (Windows Unicode(x64) found version 34.0, Android (ARM) at line 27 (27:135) -- What can I do to fix this as I cannot compile with this error. It has to do with SHA512 and I am not using that.

Comment: Correction, that last error was for: \Hashes\DCPsha256.dcu - but same problem - got ARM but expected Win64. I have no idea how to fix this!!!

Comment: Use Build project command, it will rebuild all units.

Comment: To avoid this, set "Output directory"=.\$(Platform)\$(Config)
This will create .\Win32\debug for win32, .\Win64\debug for win64, etc. for binary files like DCUs and EXEs